# How to make optgroup collapsed by default with javascript or jquery without using library

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, bootstrap-4

Good day all, I want to achieve an optgroup collapsed by default as seen in the picture below, using JavaScript or jQuery, using select 2 or any other library is not an option. I just want to see how I can use JavaScript to get it collapsed, thanks.

.[image]

My current code is below, I couldn't get it collapsed by default

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Lagos">
    <option> Yaba </option>
    <option> Ikeja </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Abuja">
    <option> Wuse </option>
    <option> Area 1 </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: they are collapsed by default.

Comment: Not collapsed here sir, not even on when I run it on stack overflow